# Selenium testing notapad app senKeys 'i' but writes it 'ı'. Why notepad do not recognize 'i'

Tags: java, selenium, appium, notepad

Here is my test code:
textArea method

```
    public WebElement textArea(){
        return driver.findElementByClassName("Edit");
    }
```

test method

```
   @Test
    public void testNotepad(){
        System.out.println("test");
        np.textArea().sendKeys("iii");
        Assert.assertEquals(np.textArea().getText(),
                "iii");
        np.textArea().sendKeys(Keys.ALT, Keys.F4);
        np.dialogCancel().click();
        np.textArea().sendKeys(Keys.ALT, Keys.F4);
        np.dialogDontSave().click();

    }
```

Error:
java.lang.AssertionError:
Expected :iii
Actual   :ııı

I am trying to text on notepad and close without saving it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to set locale before you type?

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US"));
```

And in general to play with the [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) setting.

Comment: It does not work for me. May be it is about local settings. Thanks for response.